# Select once for duplicate record

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

This is my tables which I need get data from these tables. Each user can under many type of `groups` for example **2, 3, 4**

```
1)groups
|gp_id|gp_name|gp_status|
-------------------------------------
|  1  | Admin | Active |
|  2  | R&D   | Active |
|  3  | Sales | Active |
|  4  |  IT   | Active |

2)modules         (FK of table parent_modules)
|mod_id| mod_name|        pmod_id          |
---------------------------------------------
|  1   | name1   |            1            |
|  2   | name2   |            1            |
|  3   | name3   |            2            |
|  4   | name4   |            3            |
| ...  | name... |            3            |
mod_id = 5,6,7.. and so on

3)parent_modules
|pmod_id|    mod_name      |pmod_status|
-----------------------------------------
|  1    | Contact Us       |  Active    |
|  2    | Account Settings |  Active    |
|  3    | System Settings  |  Active    |

4)group_details
         (FK of table groups)  (FK of table modules) 
|gpd_id |    gp_id           |       mod_id          | base_gpd_rule_view/edit/update/insert |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1    |          3         |          1            |     on        |
|  2    |          3         |          2            |     on        |
|  3    |          3         |          3            |               |
|  4    |          3         |          4            |
|  5    |          3         |          5            |     on        |
|  6    |          3         |          6            |
|  7    |          3         |          7            |
|  8    |          4         |          6            |
|  9    |          4         |          7            |     on        |
|  10   |          4         |          8            |     on        |
```

I have to select once only of duplicate results from `group_details` and this is the result that I want.

```
|    gp_id           |       mod_id          |
----------------------------------------------
|          3         |          1            |
|          3         |          2            |
|          3         |          3            |
|          3         |          4            | 
|          3         |          5            |
|          3         |          6            |
|          3         |          7            |
|          4         |          8            |
```

So far this is what I did in my query but it shows me duplicate record.

```
//get user groups store in database. example group in database:2, 3, 4
$GroupList = explode(", ", $UserDetail['u_group']); 
foreach($GroupList as $a)
{
    $getParentModuleSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM parent_modules WHERE pmod_status<>'Disable'" );
    $count1 = base_num_rows($getParentModuleSQL);

    while($ParentModuledata_row = base_fetch_array($getParentModuleSQL))
    if ($count1!= 0)
    {
         base_executeSQL("SELECT gp.gp_id AS ID FROM group_details AS gp, modules AS m WHERE m.pmod_id =". $ParentModuledata_row['pmod_id'] ." AND gp.gp_id=". $a ." AND gp.mod_id = m.mod_id" AND (base_gpd_rule_view='on' OR base_gpd_rule_add='on' OR base_gpd_rule_edit='on' OR base_gpd_rule_delete='on') GROUP BY gp.mod_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you want to see `4 | 6` and `4 | 7`, they dont appear to be duplicates? or do you mean only where mod_id is a duplicate? in which case, which gp_id do you want to see for the mod_id? or do you want to see all gp_id for the mod_id, but only in one row?

Comment: basically what I need to do is something like this. [check here](http://a1javascripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Drop-Menu.jpg) whereas parent_modules is the category page and modules is sub nav link.

Comment: i get that. but `mod_id` 6 has `gp_id` 3 & 4. how do you want to decide which `gp_id` to select?

Comment: It will either choose one of the `gp_id` 3/4 and ignore the rest with the duplicate data

Comment: Then just group by mod_id

Comment: Basically I have done with the list down the **category** and **sub nav link**. And I just edited my code above. When I allow `gp_id` 3 to deal with `mod_id` 15 & 16 and do the same actions to `gp_id` 4, it will show me two same category.

Comment: Post the query that is giving you the wrong result

Comment: the query is written at above. Here is my sample screenshot that give me wrong result [HERE](http://imgur.com/VCo100v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still dont understand your problems. if you want all modules a gp_id has access to - `select * from group_details where gp_id = XX`. If you just want each module, `select * from modules`.

Comment: It's ok..The query that I wrote at above is list down the category which marked as checked (base_gdp_rule_view=on). My problem is when I checked all permission in group 3, it will list down **System Setting**. but when I did the same things to group 4, it will list down 2 **System Setting** in my main category but I only have to display once.

Comment: can you please create some sample tables and data on sqlfiddle.com ? that'll help a lot

Comment: [Sample Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/657f4c/1) You may check here, do I need do create other tables as well?

Comment: I got my answer here already. Thank you :)
[Answer](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bc31/3)